# Unity Player Movement Script nullifies gravity

Tags: unity, unityscript

i want my Player to be affected by gravity, while being able to be moved in horizontal direction(the Player jumps up and down), but my script:

```
Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), (Input.GetAxis("Vertical")), 0);

transform.position += move * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

...seems to nullifiy gravity. Can someone tell me how to fix that?

Comment: You should use Rigidbody.AddForce and steer very clear of altering the position by its transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Savlon wrote:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html
or this:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html 
But do not use "transform.position +=" for player movement script.

Comment: `Transform.Translate` and `transform.position +=` do very similar things in terms of interference with rigidbody physics, so I would not recommend using any `Transform` component positioning at all if you intend to move the body physically.